# How to table and assign an array of object there?

Tags: java, user-interface

[image]
How to create something like this using GUI java?

Just this red framework i have highlighted.

Comment: JTable in swing and TableView in FX

Comment: If only there were tutorials for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a list but a [`Table`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

---

Here is the documentation for Swing and JavaFX about tables.

[**JavaFX**](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)

**[Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)**